# Error messages: with Copy constructor and Overloaded assignment operator

Tags: c++, overloading, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

This is a question earlier asked by me. 
I'm getting compilation errors using the copy constructor suggested by the forum.

```
class A
{
private:
    int a;
    int b;


public:

    A() { a = 0; b = 0; }
    int getA() { return a; }
    int getB() { return b; }
    A(const Beta& b) :a{ *b.X() }, b{ *b.Y } {} 

};

class Beta
{
private:
    int *x;
    int *y;

public:
    Beta(int a, int b) { x =&a; y = &b; }
    int* X() { return x; }
    int* Y() { return y; }

};

int main()
{
    B aObject;
    Alpha a1 = aBObject;
    Alpha a2;
    a2 = aBObject;

    return 0;

}
```

Without const   Alpha(Beta& be) in the copy constructor argument

```
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'Beta' 
Error   C2228   left of '.getY' must have class/struct/union 
Error   C2228   left of '.getX' must have class/struct/union 
Error   C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Beta' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'Beta' to 'Alpha' 
Error   C2065   'be': undeclared identifier 
Error   C2535   'Alpha::Alpha(void)': member function already defined or declared
```

With const   Alpha(const Beta& be) in the copy constructor argument

```
Error (active)  the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "Beta::getX" 
Error (active)  the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "Beta::getY" 

Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'Beta' 
Error   C2228   left of '.getY' must have class/struct/union 
Error   C2228   left of '.getX' must have class/struct/union 
Error   C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Beta' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'Beta' to 'Alpha' 
Error   C2065   'be': undeclared identifier 
Error   C2535   'Alpha::Alpha(void)': member function already defined or declared
```

Comment: `Alpha(const Beta& be)` is not a copy constructor.  Beta needs to be declared before Alpha can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
class Beta
{
private:
    int *x;
    int *y;

public:
    Beta() { x = nullptr; y = nullptr; }
    int* getX() { return x; }
    int* getY() { return y; }

};

class Alpha
{
private:
    int a;
    int b;


public:

    Alpha() { a = 0; b = 0; }
    int getA() { return a; }
    int getB() { return b; }
    Alpha( Beta& be) :a{ *be.getX() }, b{ *be.getY() } {} 
//It is not copy Constructor. You can't pass const reference here because getX getY returns pointer. So it could break const contract

};



int main()
{
    Beta aBetaObject;
    Alpha a1 = aBetaObject;
    Alpha a2;
    a2 = aBetaObject;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You can pass `const Beta&` if you declare the Beta get methods as const, eg `int* getX() const { return x; }`.

Comment: More to the point Paul brought up, `getX` and `getY` returning a pointer has *nothing* to do with the reason `Beta& be` must be non-const with the given definition of `Beta`. It's simply because those member functions are declared non-const. The pointer value returns have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. But AFAIK you should never do something like
 int* getX() const { return x; }
because you promise not to change internal state of Beta but you really can do it

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the order of the class but still getting Error C2276 '*": illegal operation on bound member function expression on Alpha( Beta& be) :a{ *be.getX() }, b{ *be.getY() } {}. Is this code sufficent to run the statements I.  Alpha a1 = aBetaObject;
II. Alpha a2; III. a2 = aBetaObject;

Answer (score 0):

There are no copy constructors (or assignment operators) in your code. But anyway that's not the issue. They issue that your code for `Alpha` uses `Beta` before `Beta` has been defined. That's what the compiler is complaining about, it doesn't recognise `Beta` at the point you first use it.

Just move `Beta` so it's definition is before `Alpha` and everything will compile.